# Create global buildx builder for Jenkins pipeline

Tags: docker, jenkins, buildx

We are currently trying to support multi-arch image builds on our jenkins runners.
The runner is hosted on an EC2 spot instance on AWS using a custom AMI of Amazon Linux 2 which contains some build requirements. Which now already includes a configured buildx builder.

But, when running a pipeline that contains a `docker buildx build ...` command the jenkins pipeline fails complaining about the fact that the default docker builder does not support multi-platform builds. Meaning that the builder doesn't exist somehow in the context of the pipeline.

I have installed the buildx builder in the AMI using following commands:

```
docker run --privileged --rm tonistiigi/binfmt --install all
docker buildx create --name multi-arch-builder --use
```

Creating a custom EC2 instance using this AMI and executing the same `docker buildx build ...` command that gets executing in the jenkins pipeline works fine.

---

I also added a shell command to see if the builder is even visible for the jenkins pipeline:

```
docker buildx use multi-arch-builder
```

This results in an error, because the builder could not be found.

The only other solution I currently have is to add the creation of the buildx builder to each pipeline... Which is not ideal.

Comment: Did you figure this out? Currently getting ready to do the same thing. I'd like to create a pre-installed builder in my CI agent image. `buildx use` has a [`--global` flag](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/buildx_use/) but I'm not sure if that's correct or has other implications

Comment: I have narrowed down the cause, due to the fact that a new terminal session or something similar is occuring. I have "fixed" this issue by creating a new builder right before I need it and that seems to work fine.