# Azure DevOps share buildx builder between jobs

Tags: docker, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, cicd, buildx

We are currently trying to support multiarch images for different services that get built in explicit jobs. We have a `setup` job that creates the `buildx builder` and then a job for each service that builds the multiarch images.
Now currently our problem is that the `buildx builder` is not shared between jobs and so the service-multiarch-images cannot be built.

Output from a service-job:

```
ERROR: no builder "multiarchBuilder" found
##[error]PowerShell exited with code '1'.
```

Our `build-docker-images.yml`:

```yaml
name: build-docker-images

trigger: none

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

variables:
  - template: globals.yml

jobs:
  - job: setup
    displayName: 'Setup'
    steps:
      - checkout: self
        persistCredentials: true

      - pwsh: |
          docker run --rm --privileged tonistiigi/binfmt --install all
        displayName: "Install QEMU emulators"

      - pwsh: |
          buildx create --name multiarchBuilder --driver=docker-container --driver-opt image=moby/buildkit:latest
        displayName: "Create builder for docker buildx"

  - job: build_obfuscated_service_docker_image
    dependsOn: setup
    displayName: 'Build obfuscated_service docker image'
    steps:
      - pwsh: |
          docker buildx bake -f ./docker/docker-compose.yml --set "*.context=." --builder default --set "obfuscated_service.tags=docker_obfuscated_service:latest" --load obfuscated_service

  - job: build_obfuscated_service_2_docker_image
    dependsOn: setup
    displayName: 'Build obfuscated_service_2 docker image'
    steps:
      - pwsh: |
          docker buildx bake -f ./docker/docker-compose.yml --set "*.context=." --builder default --set "obfuscated_service_2.tags=docker_obfuscated_service_2:latest" --load obfuscated_service_2 

    ...[more jobs for more services]
```

We would like to keep the approach with explicit services for clearity and extensibility. We would like to keep creating the `buildx builder` in the setup job and not for each job seperately as described in this [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74458513/create-global-buildx-builder-for-jenkins-pipeline#comment133121971_74458513).

Is there a way to share the `docker buildx builder` between jobs?